# Getting a ray for raypicking in openGL ES

Tags: android, opengl-es, ray-picking

OK, so I used this code for a ray for opengl ES but I'm getting an error with the

```
this.P0 = farCoOrds;
this.P1 = nearCoOrds;
```

at the very end of the code. It says,

> Cannot Resolve Symbol

Here is the code:

```
public class Ray {
    public static float[] P0 = new float[3];
    public static float [] P1 = new float[3];
    public Ray(GL10 gl, int width, int height, float xTouch, float yTouch) {
        MatrixGrabber matrixGrabber = new MatrixGrabber();
        matrixGrabber.getCurrentState(gl);

        int[] viewport = {0, 0, width, height};

        float[] nearCoOrds = new float[3];
        float[] farCoOrds = new float[3];
        float[] temp = new float[4];
        float[] temp2 = new float[4];
        // get the near and far ords for the click
        float winx = xTouch, winy =(float)viewport[3] - yTouch;
    //        Log.d(TAG, "modelView is =" + Arrays.toString(matrixGrabber.mModelView));
    //        Log.d(TAG, "projection view is =" + Arrays.toString( matrixGrabber.mProjection ));

        int result = GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, 1.0f, matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0, 
    matrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, viewport, 0, temp, 0);

        Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2, 0, matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0, temp, 0);
        if(result == GL10.GL_TRUE){
            nearCoOrds[0] = temp2[0] / temp2[3];
            nearCoOrds[1] = temp2[1] / temp2[3];
            nearCoOrds[2] = temp2[2] / temp2[3];

        }

        result = GLU.gluUnProject(winx, winy, 0, matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0,    
    matrixGrabber.mProjection, 0, viewport, 0, temp, 0);
        Matrix.multiplyMV(temp2,0,matrixGrabber.mModelView, 0, temp, 0);
        if(result == GL10.GL_TRUE){
            farCoOrds[0] = temp2[0] / temp2[3];
            farCoOrds[1] = temp2[1] / temp2[3];
            farCoOrds[2] = temp2[2] / temp2[3];
        }
        this.P0 = farCoOrds;
        this.P1 = nearCoOrds;
    }   
}
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Where are `P0` and `P1` defined?

Comment: It isn't I guess what I am asking is what are they suppose to be defined as.

Answer (score 0):

The P0 [] and the P1 [] are not defined. I defined them as public static float[] P0 = new float[3], and public static float[] P1 = new float[3].